# How to solve errors in Codename One when loading sqlite db file (simulator & device)?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, codenameone

I am trying to copy a preloaded .db file created by DB Browser for SQLite   to my app made in Codename One. I have placed the app into my src folder and theme.res folder (under Data) and have added the following code into my `init()` method of the opening class of my app:

```
 String path = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath("mydb.db");

    Log.p("init path = " + path);
    FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();

    if(path != null && !fs.exists(path)) {
        Log.p("path != null ");
        try (OutputStream os = fs.openOutputStream(path);
        InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/mydb.db");
             ) {
            Util.copy(is, os);
        } catch (IOException err) {
            Log.e(err);
            //copyDb(path);
        }
    }
```

`path`returns a variable.  When running the **simulator**, I get this error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_CORRUPT]  The database disk image is malformed (database disk image is malformed)
```

On my **Android device** I get this message:

```
Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException - no such table:
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the values of `UCSConstantsAndCommons.DB` & `UCSConstantsAndCommons.DB_PATH`

Comment: "mydb.db" and "/mydb.db" respectively. I made these changes above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the values for the variables are incorrect and produce the wrong result. Since this happens on the simulator it's pretty easy to debug. Just check the file is correct under the `.cn1` directory in your user home directory.

Comment: When I check that folder I only have an empty `localstorage` folder and `.lock` file. Where did my db go?

Comment: That means the file wasn't copied into place. It might be because the database directory is missing in which case that's probably a bug. Create the folder `database` in the `.cn1` directory and see if it works around this, if so we need to fix that. I thing `getDatabasePath` should implicitly create that directory if it doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks @Shai Almog. In my case I tried to open my db file in Sqlite Browser and got a message that the database was malformed, similar to the one I saw when trying to run it through the simulator. When I replaced that db file with an alternate, placed it in src folder and replaced the file name in my code, it thankfully worked.